# Calculate Sums from 1 Column Up to Value in Another, then Total Sum

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
User<- c("User1", "User1","User1", "User1","User1", "User1","User1", "User2","User2","User2","User2","User2","User2","User2")
Touchpoints <- c("A", "B", "C", "F", "D", "E", "H","A", "B", "K", "D", "E", "F", "M")
Conversion <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)
Frequency<-c(1,2,3,0,4,5,0,1,2,0,0,3,4,5)
df<-data.frame(User, Touchpoints, Conversion, Frequency)
df$Exponential<-ifelse(df$Frequency>0, exp(df$Frequency), 0)

df
    User Touchpoints Conversion Frequency Exponential
1  User1           A          0         1    2.718282
2  User1           B          0         2    7.389056
3  User1           C          0         3   20.085537
4  User1           F          1         0    0.000000
5  User1           D          0         4   54.598150
6  User1           E          0         5  148.413159
7  User1           H          1         0    0.000000
8  User2           A          0         1    2.718282
9  User2           B          0         2    7.389056
10 User2           K          1         0    0.000000
11 User2           D          1         0    0.000000
12 User2           E          0         3   20.085537
13 User2           F          0         4   54.598150
14 User2           M          1         5  148.413159
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to take the percentage of the `Exponential` value represented by `_Conv` from the sum of the `Exponential` Column by `User` up to that `Conversion` value. Here is an example:

```
    User Touchpoints Conversion Frequency Exponential   Sum of Exp    1st_Conv   Sum_Exp_for_Conv2     2nd_Conv
1  User1           A          0         1    2.718282       30.192      0.0900             233.204       0.0116
2  User1           B          0         2    7.389056       30.192      0.2447             233.204       0.0317
3  User1           C          0         3   20.085537       30.192      0.6652             233.204       0.0861
4  User1           F          1         0    0.000000            0      0.0000             233.204            0     
5  User1           D          0         4   54.598150            0      0.0000             233.204       0.2341
6  User1           E          0         5  148.413159            0      0.0000             233.204       0.6364
7  User1           H          1         0    0.000000            0      0.0000                   0            0
8  User2           A          0         1    2.718282       10.107      0.2689              10.107       0.2689
9  User2           B          0         2    7.389056       10.107      0.7311              10.107       0.7311
10 User2           K          1         0    0.000000            0      0.0000                   0            0
11 User2           D          1         0    0.000000            0      0.0000                   0            0
12 User2           E          0         3   20.085537            0      0.0000                   0            0
13 User2           F          0         4   54.598150            0      0.0000                   0            0
14 User2           M          0         5  148.413159            0      0.0000                   0            0
```

There will be cases where there will be over 100 conversions per user and doing it this way would create thousands of columns, seems like it is not scalable.

My ultimate output is to sum all of the `_Conv` into one final column called `Final_Conv`. For this example, the final output would look like this:

```
        User Touchpoints Conversion Frequency   Final_Conv
    1  User1           A          0         1       0.1017      
    2  User1           B          0         2       0.2764
    3  User1           C          0         3       0.7514
    4  User1           F          1         0            0
    5  User1           D          0         4       0.2341
    6  User1           E          0         5       0.6364
    7  User1           H          1         0            0
    8  User2           A          0         1       0.5379
    9  User2           B          0         2       1.4621
    10 User2           K          1         0            0
    11 User2           D          1         0            0
    12 User2           E          0         3            0
    13 User2           F          0         4            0
    14 User2           M          0         5            0
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the simplest code, but we can do something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number(),
         conv_id = cumsum(Conversion),
         exp_cumsum = cumsum(Exponential)) %>%
  group_by(conv_id, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(sum_of_exp = ifelse(n()==1, NA, last(exp_cumsum))) %>%
  spread(conv_id, sum_of_exp, sep = "_") %>%
  arrange(User, row_id) %>%
  fill(!!!vars(starts_with("conv_id")), .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("conv_id")), funs(Exponential/.)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Final_Conv = rowSums(.[-(1:7)], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(1:4, Final_Conv)
```

**Notes:**

I first created a cumulative sum of `Conversion` and `Exponential`, added `conv_id` as an additional grouping variable, and replaced all values in each `User` + `conv_id` combination with the last value of `exp_cumsum`. Then, spread the `conv_id` and `sum_of_exp` columns and filled each `conv_id_` column up. Finally, used `mutate_at` to divide `Exponential` by each of the `conv_id_` columns and created `Final_Conv` by summing all resultant `conv_id_` columns with `rowSums`.

This solution should work for an arbitrary number of `Conversion`s for each `User`.

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 14 x 5
     User Touchpoints Conversion Frequency Final_Conv
   <fctr>      <fctr>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1  User1           A          0         1  0.1016868
 2  User1           B          0         2  0.2764134
 3  User1           C          0         3  0.7513695
 4  User1           F          1         0  0.0000000
 5  User1           D          0         4  0.2341217
 6  User1           E          0         5  0.6364086
 7  User1           H          1         0  0.0000000
 8  User2           A          0         1  0.3010000
 9  User2           B          0         2  0.8182029
10  User2           K          1         0  0.0000000
11  User2           D          1         0  0.0000000
12  User2           E          0         3  0.2368828
13  User2           F          0         4  0.6439143
14  User2           M          1         5  0.0000000
```

Comment: This is amazing, this worked great! Thanks for your help

Comment: @nak5120 The values for `User2` are a bit off versus your final output. Please check whether they are correct. I think `Conversion` should be 1 in row 14.

Comment: You're right, I just wrote it down wrong in the beginning.